# jQuery cycle plugin "before" and "after" callbacks firing on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I'm using the cycle plugin to bind some functions before and after a slide is shown, this works fine using the `before` and `after` callbacks but the functions are also fired when the plugin initially loads, here's a simplified version of the code:

```
$(function() {

    $('.slider').cycle({
        before : function() {
            alert('this shouldn\'t appear on cycle load');             
        },
        after: function() {
            alert('this shouldn\'t appear on cycle load');             
        }           
    });

});​
```

See [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vengiss/gshtZ/4/) for example. The alerts are shown right after the page loads and also before and after each slide transition, is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to specify `skipInitializationCallbacks: true` (undocumented) in your options to avoid getting the callbacks on startup.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gshtZ/6/)